# Ceiling paint shiny

Tags: ceiling, paint

Painted ceiling with a flat finish white paint. Lowes matched color perfectly, but it is much more shiny tha the rest of ceiling even thought he finish is flat. 
Any options or observations

Comment: Did you stir the can *thoroughly* before using?  If you painted out of a cup (rather than roller tray) did you keep that agitated?  I have a constant problem on alkyd paints and LPUs with the flattening agent separating while I'm painting... could probably happen on latex too...

Answer (score 2):

### Nope.  Just Nope.

Don't paint a single wall or ceiling *from different cans*.

The human eye can see millions of colors and dozens of different sheens. You will get caught, it's a simple as that.

And to make matters worse, the squirt mixer can be a little off from can to can, so even two cans of the same thing to the same formula may not be identical.

So how do you handle this?  The answer is you mix all your paint up carefully (so there isn't any pigment in the bottom or the lid), and then dump them all into one big bucket and stir.  Feel free to pour the paint back into the original cans at that point.

What do you do when you run out of paint?  First, be savvy enough not to *start* a wall or ceiling unless you have enough paint to finish.  The easy way is to go back and get the exact same kind and mix of paint (bring the old can).  It may still not match *precisely*, but it is much harder to compare different surfaces.

If you can't get that, then do your level best to match in a competitor paint, and again, use the competitor paint to paint the entire wall or ceiling.

If you *did* start a wall or ceiling and ran out midstream, be prepared to recoat that entire wall or ceiling.

If you need 1-1/4 gallons and you have a half gallon left, and you need to go with a competitor brand,  then make absolutely sure the new brand is compatible with your remaining paint, because you must mix them as above.

If two surfaces are at different angles, it is hard to compare them precisely.  You are counting on this effect to conceal any difference in paint.  That means don't slop paint over an edge.  Paint a sharp clean edge from wall to ceiling or at a corner.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

Flare the newly painted area - blending the area where the two paints meet and overlap.  This will mitigate the contrast between the two areas.

Go back to lowes and ask them to mix up a batch of flat paint to match the original.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons for this I will try to explain each.

When you use a color match paint the scenario is you take your paint scrap to the HW store and they place it in a Spectrometer to read the spectra of that paint. This type of spectrometer is a reflective measurement spectrometer. Basically what happens is light is bounced off of the patch you have provided and the returned light is examined by the electronics to declare what the color of the item is.

There are several things that come into play here and I will try to avoid too much detail.

1: This method is using LIGHT as its basis your paints are a pigment base and there are calculations made to transform this LIGHT data into a Pigment data - it has to do with a thing called Color Spaces - even your monitor versus a CRT vs your printer has this.

2: The Spectrometer must be calibrated properly - chances are very good your lowes store with all good intents did not properly calibrate the spectrometer. In a photo lab they are quick calibrated before every use and fine tune calibrated every day. Probably does not happen in a hardware store but more likely in a Paint store - you would hope and think so anyway.

3: Your original paint was not FLAT based paint. The spectrometer picked up on a particular reflection (or can pick up on a shadow) created by the surface of the paint. Much harder to match Matte, Eggshell surfaces.

So this is a SMALL sample of what can go wrong and why color matching can be a bear.

The other problem that can occur is the paint mixer station can have malfunctions, can fail to squirt enough paint to color the paint. Larger Batches will match more closely than a 1/2 pint for sure.

**Now on to the Fix.**

- Paint the rest of the ceiling is your best option.
- Go to a real paint store and try to match the ceiling - repaint your shiny ceiling. Keep in mind that shiny ceiling paint is your 'underlayment' and may cause a perceived color variation.